# VBA userform button to save sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a excel document which is managed by different userforms. I want to add a save option (button) to one of my userforms after the document was edited.

Therefore I want to know if there is code which will open the **Save** or **Save as...** window?

What I want to achieve is to save the file as a normal .xsl file and not .xslm file in a location which the user can choose (from a userform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this... ?

```
Sub test()

Dim vSave_File As Variant

vSave_File = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Test.xls", "Excel files (*.xls),*.xls", 1, "Dialog Title")

End Sub
```